# how to check random words in string become the current word in Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, if-statement

how to check random words in string to be the current words which we put in object
temp to check in string :

```
 obj = {
            two: 2,
            three: 3    
        }
```

if I have those string `WTWTHROETEO` it means those string words `['TWO', 'TWO' ,'THREE']`

why `['TWO', 'TWO' ,'THREE']` ? because on those strings are random words and we should make those randoms words become the. current words in objects

here is the `input` :

`let str = 'WTWTHROETEO'`

and the `output` I wanted is:
`[ 2,2,3 ]`

Comment: Here is not that there are not attempts to make the code work, here there are not attempts to make the question to be understandable

Comment: I updated a. bit @quirimmo

Comment: I am sorry, maybe my fault, but I still do not understand it. Can you rephrase your question as: 1) input 2) expected output 3) code you have tried so far? this would make the question a bit more understandable

Comment: can you check again? I updated again :D @quirimmo

Comment: I cannot really understand why `'WTWTHROETEO'` means `['TWO', 'TWO', 'THREE']` ?

Comment: TWOTWOTHREE is jumbled ad WTWTHROETEO

Comment: because those string is alphabets randoms, the two two and threes are on those `str`

Comment: @AshayMandwarya yep correct

Comment: How would we know what words we have to find because in your string we can find where woo the and many other words

Comment: I just want to store 2 numbers in those string which in `object` to check them :D @AshayMandwarya f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a first draft of what you could try to do.

You can of course refactor and improve it.

Get an array of all the lowercase chars of your string.

Then for each key in your object, get an array of all the lower case chars of your key.

While your key chars are all included in your string array, increment the object counter of that key, and remove those chars from the input string array.

Then get back your output with the values of your keys for all the times they have been counted in

```js
function getOccurrences(inputString, obj) {
  let stringArray = inputString.toLowerCase().split('');
  let countObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(checkKeyPresenceInString);

  return Object.entries(countObj)
    .map(getValuesFromKeys)
    .flat();

  function checkKeyPresenceInString(key) {
    countObj[key] = 0;
    const keyArray = key.toLowerCase().split('');
    // while all the chars of your key are included in your input string
    while (keyArray.every(e => stringArray.includes(e))) {
      countObj[key]++;
      keyArray.forEach(removeAllChars);
    }
  }

  function removeAllChars(c) {
    stringArray.splice(stringArray.indexOf(c), 1);
  }

  function getValuesFromKeys([key, value]) {
    return new Array(value).fill(obj[key]);
  }
}

const obj = { two: 2, three: 3 };
let string = 'WTWTHROETEO';
console.log(getOccurrences(string, obj));

const obj2 = { two: 2, three: 3, four: 4 };
let string2 = 'FWTWOUTHROETEOR';
console.log(getOccurrences(string2, obj2));

const obj3 = { two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5, six: 6};
let string3 = 'VEXFIIFWSTWOUTHROESTIEXOSRIVXEFIX';
console.log(getOccurrences(string3, obj3));
```

Comment: I try to understanding your codes, thanks for your help:D

Comment: added comments all over the code, but I would like to refactor it a bit honestly, that's a pretty mess code yet :)

Comment: @poppop refactoring the code and added some other cases at the end, with four and five, just to see if it works properly

Answer (score 0):

You could get a brute force approach and generate all combinations of the given words and take this words as base for getting a number.

```js
function getWords(random) {
    function getSorted (s) {
        return Array.from(s).sort().join();
    }

    function fork(i, t) {
        var temp = t.join('');
        if (sorted === getSorted(temp)) {
            result.push(t);
            return;
        }
        if (temp.length >= sorted.length || i === keys.length) {
            return;
        }
        fork(i, t.concat([keys[i]]));
        fork(i + 1, t);
    }

    var result = [],
        sorted = getSorted(random);
        
    fork(0, []);
    return result;
}

var object = { TWO: 2, THREE: 3 },
    keys = Object.keys(object).sort(({ length: a }, { length: b }) => a - b),
    words = getWords('WTWTHROETEO'),
    numbers = words.map(keys => keys.map(k => object[k]));

console.log(words);
console.log(numbers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```